# regex for getting specific nested element in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get specific element nested in few elements with regex and with out using dom parser library and queryselector method.

Regex:

```
  <art .*?id="src".*?>(?:\s+)?<section .*?class="product".*?>(?:\s+)?<h3>(?:\s+)?(.+?)(?:\s+)?<\/h3><\/section>(?:\s+)?<\/art>
```

Content:

```
<art id="src">
  <section class="product">
    <h3>xvd</h3>
    <p>
     sjfdsjvdvds
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="product">
    <h3>avdsvd</h3>
    <p>
    djsfdsjgdjs
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="product">
    <h3>zdvdsv</h3>
    <p>
 safdgdsghhrh
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="product">
    <h3>dd</h3>
    <p>zscsvdsvdsv</p>
  </section>
</art>
```

Please help me in correcting regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you can likely get those `h3` `textContent`s using,

```
<section .*?class="product".*?>\s*<h3>\s*(.+?)\s*<\/h3>.*?<\/section>\s*
```

then if you have to check for `art` element, maybe altering with,

```
<section .*?class="product".*?>\s*<h3>\s*(.+?)\s*<\/h3>.*?<\/section>\s*|<art .*?id="src".*?>
```

would be an option, otherwise it'd be pretty complicated with JavaScript.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tlYXx6/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tlYXx6/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/tlYXx6/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

```js
const regex = /<section .*?class="product".*?>\s*<h3>\s*(.+?)\s*<\/h3>.*?<\/section>\s*|<art .*?id="src".*?>/gs;
const str = `<art id="src">
  <section class="product">
    <h3>xvd</h3>
    <p>
     sjfdsjvdvds
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="product">
    <h3>avdsvd</h3>
    <p>
    djsfdsjgdjs
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="product">
    <h3>zdvdsv</h3>
    <p>
 safdgdsghhrh
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="product">
    <h3>dd</h3>
    <p>zscsvdsvdsv</p>
  </section>
</art>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: could you please help me with the? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259069/regex-is-not-matching-data-in-javascript